# How can I create horizontal view scrolling like the News & Weather app?

Tags: android, layout, scroll

Android News & Weather app lets you swipe to reveal another view, just like the iPhone. Can someone show me an example of how this is done?

It is not a ViewFlipper attached to a GestureDetector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom view, you can see how it's done in Launcher by looking at Workspace.java in packages/apps/Launcher2 at android.git.kernel.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this out-of-the-box in the Android Compatibility library with a ViewPager:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html?m=1

ViewPager slides between Fragments much the same way ListViews scroll up and down with views.

If you're not interested in scrolling the tabs, there's an example in the SDK that uses a TabHost (instead of making the tabs themselves scrollable left-to-right), but you need not use a TabHost.  You could, if you wanted horizontally-scrolling tabs, use a HorizontalScrollView with some buttons in it.

For an approach that doesn't use the compatibility lib, or fragments, see here:  https://github.com/olibye/AndroViews